# Angularjs inject provider into module factory function by string name for minification

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
appModule = angular.module('appModule', []);

appModule.factory('sharedApplication', function($rootScope, $http) {
  var sharedApp;
  sharedApp = {};
  sharedApp.currentView = "home-section";
  sharedApp.pastEvents = null;
  $http.get('api/highlights').success(function(response) {
    return sharedApp.pastEvents = response.data;
  });
  return sharedApp;
});
```

This code works perfectly and as expected until I try to minify my javascript and then I get

```
    Error: Unknown provider: eProvider <- e
```

This is because the $http argument in my factory function has been renamed to 'e' for minification purposes. So how can I manually inform the appModule what to inject by name to avoid minification breaking my code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try

```
appModule.factory('sharedApplication', ['$rootScope','$http',function($rootScope, $http) {

}]);
```

regards

Comment: I used the array syntax 100% of the time for this reason - IMO the other syntax you've used above should be deprecated.  Who doesn't minify their code at some point?

Comment: I am having similar factory with inside $http call like you, dont you have some issues that pastEvents is not ready when sharedApplication factory is initialized?

Comment: IMO, minification-safe syntax should be the default for all of the examples in the Angular docs.

Comment: Yes, this syntax is maybe the best for minification, but it is also violating DRY principle. Every time you need to add or change a dependency, you'll have to modify the array and the parameters. While annotations seems to be more of a right aproach, I'm not sure if it can be applied to interceptors

Answer (score 2):

[ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) is also a good library so that the required dependency is injected automatically. You should check it out.

Code sample:

```
/* ngInject */
appModule.factory('sharedApplication', function($rootScope, $http) {
  var sharedApp;
  sharedApp = {};
  sharedApp.currentView = "home-section";
  sharedApp.pastEvents = null;
  $http.get('api/highlights').success(function(response) {
    return sharedApp.pastEvents = response.data;
  });
  return sharedApp;
});
```

Then you don't have to write:

```
appModule.factory('sharedApplication', ['$rootScope','$http', 
function($rootScope, $http) {
 var sharedApp;
 sharedApp = {};
 sharedApp.currentView = "home-section";
 sharedApp.pastEvents = null;
 $http.get('api/highlights').success(function(response) {
 return sharedApp.pastEvents = response.data;
});

return sharedApp;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The more elegant and easier to read approach:

```
appModule.factory('myFactory', myFactory);

myFactory.$inject = ['$rootScope','$http'];
function myFactory($rootScope, $http) {
    ...
}
```